# Running cucumber scenario outline in parallel

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have a feature with one scenario outline that takes too long to run because of the number of examples I use. I would like to take advantage of the multiple threads available and run these outlines in parallel. One way is to split up the feature/scenario outline into multiple features. This works but then it leaves me with multiple copies of the same scenario with only a difference in examples. My question is if there is a way to split this scenario outline to run in parallel without having to create multiple features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jay, I doubt there is a way to do exactly what are asking (splitting a single scenario outline into separate parallel runs). I would say if your primary concern is 'speed' regarding this test then it would be worth having duplicate features and separating the examples out so that the coverage would complete faster. I generally like to keep my scenarios below a minute unless I am doing something that is 'expansive' like the one you are describing sounds, but for those tests I run overnight and don't expect quick results.

If the feature as you say 'takes too long to run" BUT you want it to be quicker then i would suggest to simply cut into 'quicker' bite size tests that you can then run in parallel.

Even if there was a way to do what you asked, I believe you would be better off splitting up the test anyways.

Comment: Agreed. Also, if the scenario is so big it might be worth considering whether it actually needs to do all that it's doing. But it's hard to answer this question without an example.

Comment: I had started splitting these into smaller features. This is the way I have been doing it with scenario outlines but was not sure if there was a better way. The scenario outline takes 6 minutes to run through 32 examples. Just hoping to take advantage of the parallel threads and cut this time down. Thanks!